# How can I attach a clock or a calendar to my application?

Tags: android

I would like to know how i can attach the Android clock or calendar into my application.
That is when my application comes up one part of the view will be reserved for this application.

Please guide me.

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this guide for what you can and can't add, the top one is an AnalogClock

http://www.droiddraw.org/widgetguide.html

```
<AnalogClock
 id="@+id/clock1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Some are a little old so double check on android.dev if you want to see the api

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how i can attach the Android clock or calendar into my application.

Use `AnalogClock` or `DigitalClock` for the clock. There is no calendar in the Android OS.

> That is when my application comes up one part of the view will be reserved for this application.

You cannot embed another application in yours -- sorry!